# Java Swing, Make mask aligned

Tags: java, swing

I currently have the following mask:

```
MaskFormatter mask = null;
try {
    mask = new MaskFormatter(Constants.SERIAL_NUMBER_INPUT_MASK);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JFormattedTextField serialInput = new JFormattedTextField(mask);
serialInput.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 16));
serialInput.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 25, 5, 0));
serialInput.setColumns(13);
```

My problem is that the mask is shown kink of crooked and I don't know how to make it centered.

The reason for this is it starting out being "blank" (only the mask saparators)
so it starts out like this:

[image]

It is all pulled to the left but I don't know how to fix this since after characters are entered, this starts to get aligned:

[image]

Comment: Change to a fixed width font - Swing is "guessing" based on the placeholder it's using (possibly a space) at how the text should be aligned - If it's "really" important, use multiple text fields and `DocumentListener`s to move between them as they fill up - the trick here, would be been able to support pasting text :P

Comment: setHorizontalAlignment

Comment: This depends if your font is the same size for every character or not. The best solution would probably be to have 5 different boxes that tab to the next as they fill out

Comment: Yes, actually @HovercraftFullOfEels already set me in the correct path. thank you